# How to check time clashing on basis of date and name in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to figure out time clash of a person with the help of date and person name

[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGBL1.png)

i have tried sumproduct formula but no solution.

Note:

1. Start time should not be same as start time.
2. Start time should not be same as End Time.
3. End time should not conflict with start time.

Refer This Sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eM6UYy5Usjxadpi6PnY8pwmBo_Yd60260zqwqB3h9ds/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please attach (a copy of) your Google Sheet?

Comment: What is the end goal? Please specify the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: refer this sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eM6UYy5Usjxadpi6PnY8pwmBo_Yd60260zqwqB3h9ds/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I believe I have fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Please Note: This only works for the 1st clash, and shows no clash for the  2nd appointment.

---

K2:

```
=IF(A2 = A3, "1", "0")
```

L2:

```
=IF(B2 = B3, "1", "0")
```

M2:

```
=IF(K2+L2+O2=3,1,0)
```

N2:

```
=IF(M2 = 1, "Yes", "No")
```

O2:

```
=IF(ISTEXT(B2)=TRUE,1,0)
```